# Send Binary to another application using x-callback-url

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to send a binary file to another application via. `x-callback-url`. I am able to read the file as `NSData`. But i am stuck there! Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully it is a small file. There is a limit to how long a URL can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [-[NSString base64EncodedDataWithOptions:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW37) and [-[NSString base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW38).